# VBA custom function to compare values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a custom function that basically does this:

- The function is in column F and looks at column C to see what the valus is in there.
- If it is `USA_USD` it will display `USD` in colomn F
- If it is Australia_AUD the it will display `AUD` in colomn F
- etc.

```
Function The_Decider(DealCurrency, X)       
    If DealCurrency = "USA_USD" Then X = "USD"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Australia_AUD" Then X = "AUD"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Switzerland_CHF" Then X = "CHF"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "China_CNY" Then X = "CNY"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "EMU_EUR" Then X = "EUR"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Great Britain_GBP" Then X = "GBP"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Hong Kong_HKD" Then X = "HKD"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Japan_JPY" Then X = "JPY"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Korea(South)_KRW" Then X = "KRW"
    Else
    If DealCurrency = "Viet Nam_VND" Then X = "VND"
End Function
```

Why I am getting `#value` in column C?

Comment: You didn't return anything?

Comment: Your If / Then / Else _ If structure is badly formatted, and it seems to be causing you errors - you contain the whole statement "If [condition] Then [action]", and attempt to follow it with Else then another line with If - Your Else isn't referring to anything because you've already wrapped up the conclusion of your If statement with the Then portion.

Comment: You don't need to pass in X as a parameter it seems.  You need to return X, and wherever you are calling your function from, it should assign the function return value to your cell's value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't actually supply a return value at any point. Also you would probably be better going for a `Select Case` block for the sake of readability.

You should declare the return type in the function header, then use the same name as the function to return the value in your code:

```
Function The_Decider(ByVal DealCurrency As String) As String '// <~~ return type

    Dim X As String

    Select Case DealCurrency
        Case "USA_USD":             X = "USD"
        Case "Australia_AUD":       X = "AUD"
        Case "Switzerland_CHF":     X = "CHF"
        Case "China_CNY":           X = "CNY"
        Case "EMU_EUR":             X = "EUR"
        Case "Great Britain_GBP":   X = "GBP"
        Case "Hong Kong_HKD":       X = "HKD"
        Case "Japan_JPY":           X = "JPY"
        Case "Korea(South)_KRW":    X = "KRW"
        Case "Viet Nam_VND":        X = "VND"
        Case Else:                  X = "Unknown"
    End Select

    The_Decider = X '// <~~ the part that actually returns the value

End Function
```

---

Although seeing as your input appears to have the currency code in the last 3 letters, I wouldn't even use a UDF. Simply using a worksheet formula would suffice:

```
=RIGHT(C1,3)
```